# Create packages in SQL Server management studio without SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis, package

I want to create Packages in MS SQL Server Management Studio Like ORACLE Package. But i don't get any clear idea about this on Google searching.

If there any possible to create SQL package without using SSIS in SQL Server management Studio. Kindly give me some ideas about that.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: What do you mean by package - are you referring to multiple stored procedures, functions etc. grouped together?

Comment: Yeah, I just want to group a set of procedures and functions, they are related together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate such grouping using schemas. Note that schemas in SQL Server are used mainly for controlling security permissions. Below is an example:

```
CREATE SCHEMA [billing]

CREATE PROCEDURE billing.sp_IssueInvoice ( /*parameters*/ )
AS
BEGIN
    -- Your code
END

CREATE PROCEDURE billing.sp_CancelInvoice ( /*parameters*/ )
AS
BEGIN
    -- Your code
END

CREATE SCHEMA [ordering]

CREATE PROCEDURE ordering.sp_SubmitOrder ( /*parameters*/ )
AS
BEGIN
    -- Your code
END

CREATE PROCEDURE ordering.sp_UpdateOrder ( /*parameters*/ )
AS
BEGIN
    -- Your code
END
```

Wish this helps.